# Check if a photo is from unsplash url JS

Tags: javascript

I run into a problem where my regex doesn't recognize photo urls from unsplah, how can i adjust my regex to also look for photos from unsplash.
Here is my regex that I use :

```
  const reg = /((?:(?!(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)).)+)|((?:https? 
|ftp):\/\/[\S]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)(?:\?\S+=\S*(?:&\S+=\S*)*)?)/gm;
```

Comment: why not using `string.includes()` ?

Comment: what URL that match and doesn't?

Comment: I just thought that unsplash would have a certain fixed photo url but i guess ii can use includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, TRY USING 'STRING.INCLUDES'

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
      var url = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569605803663-e9337d901ff9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=749&q=80"; 
      var string = url.toLowerCase();
      var result = string.includes("unsplash");
      if(result===true){
      alert("Unsplash Image");
      }
      else{
      alert("Not a Unsplash Image");
      }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```